# combine the video creation and draw text commands in a single instruction in ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I have the following two commands which I sequentially execute in order to create a video from an image and then draw text on it from a text file.
To create a video from a singe image i use:

```
ffmpeg -framerate 30 -loop 1 -t 5 -i 1.jpg -i 3D_Transition_02.mp4 -filter_complex "[0]format=rgba,scale=1280:720,split[img][a]; [1]format=rgb24,negate,scale=1280:720[tr];[a][tr]overlay=format=gbrp[al];[img][al]alphamerge,setsar=1,format=yuva444p" -an -c:v libvpx -crf 10 -b:v 0 -quality realtime -auto-alt-ref 0 a1vp8.mkv
```

to create the text on the video I am using the following command:

```
ffmpeg -i a1vp8.mkv -vf "drawtext=enable='gte(t,.5)':box=1:boxcolor=black@.2:boxborderw=10:fontfile=Roboto-Black.ttf:fontcolor=white:fontsize=56:shadowcolor=Black:shadowx=1:shadowy=1:textfile=text.txt:y=h/2:x=10" aiwithText5.mkv
```

is there some way for me to create the video from the image (this also has filter complex in it to create the transition alpha) and once the video has been create draw text on it in a single command by combining the two commands?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply  add the drawtext at the end of the filtering.

```
ffmpeg -framerate 30 -loop 1 -t 5 -i 1.jpg -i 3D_Transition_02.mp4 -filter_complex "[0]format=rgba,scale=1280:720,split[img][a]; [1]format=rgb24,negate,scale=1280:720[tr];[a][tr]overlay=format=gbrp[al];[img][al]alphamerge,setsar=1,format=yuva444p,drawtext=enable='gte(t,.5)':box=1:boxcolor=black@.2:boxborderw=10:fontfile=Roboto-Black.ttf:fontcolor=white:fontsize=56:shadowcolor=Black:shadowx=1:shadowy=1:textfile=text.txt:y=h/2:x=10" -an -c:v libvpx -crf 10 -b:v 0 -quality realtime -auto-alt-ref 0 a1vp8.mkv
```

Comment: Thanks Gyan, once again much appreciated.
Not intending to move the goal post, but may I ask you to look at another issue I am having?

Comment: Post a new Q...

Comment: Thanks @Gyan...I have posted the new question here:
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52735998/execfile-function-with-node-and-ffmpeg-shaves-off-1-second-of-video-created)

Comment: I have created a new question based on your above solution. When I use the above solution to create text and video in a single step I am getting a ghost text effect on the later slides. The question can be found here:

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52875218/ffmpeg-alpha-and-transition-leaving-a-ghosting-effect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52875218/ffmpeg-alpha-and-transition-leaving-a-ghosting-effect)